# Unable to Verify Domain for Apple Private Email Relay Service

Tags: wordpress, amazon-lightsail, apple-sign-in

**Context:**

I am developing an iOS app with sign-in with apple. This features gives users the ability to hide their emails and use an anonymous email to register. In order to be able to send information to these email addresses apple requires you to register both your emails and domain from which emails will be sent.

I followed these 2 guides to register and verify the domain:

- https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-2/
- https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devf822fb8fc

Important to note:

- In properly follow the directions I needed to make the .well-known folder myself
- Domain is publicly accessible
- I did make sure I added `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` to my DNS records
- I already have a Let's Encrypt SSL cert

**Enviornment:**

Wordpress running on AWS Lightsail

**Problem**

When I click the verify button, I am given a 1 line error message:

> Verification failed for domain

I am not sure how to proceed with verifying my domain.

**Troubleshooting steps I have taken:**

1. Instead of verifying example.com, verify www.example.com incase it is being redirected
2. Move apple-developer-domain-association.txt to the root directory instead of /.well-known
3. Verify using Safari instead of Chrome
4. Download new verification file
5. Email Apple support (They just sent the same guide I found in their dev docs)
6. Checked to make sure I had a supported TLS 1.2 cipher using [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) (I do have 1, do I need all?)

**Response in Network Inspect Tool:**

```
{
    "responseId":"XXX",
    "resultCode":13004,
    "resultString":"Verification failed for domain",
    "userString":"Verification failed for domain",
    "creationTimestamp":"2020-01-23T21:48:37Z",
    "protocolVersion":"QH65B2",
    "userLocale":"en_US",
    "requestUrl":"https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/ios/identifiers/verifyDomain",
    "httpCode":200
}
```

Comment: what do you get when running 

nslookup -type=txt domain.com 

in terminal? does it show:  text = "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all" ?

Comment: are you clicking the verify button inside developer.apple.com under "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" and "more" and "configure"? what is the exact error message?

Comment: I am clicking the exact button you are describing and the exact error message is in fact posted above

Comment: Here are some possible solutions: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119616 When I verified my domain I only got the "Your domain is not spf compliant" error. That is probably not the root of your problem.